# Instruments CLI does not load debug symbols

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake, instruments

(Note: I've used the `xcode` tag since this question relates to Instruments which I understand to be closely tied to the XCode toolchain. Apologies if that was not appropriate.)

I am trying to use Instruments on MacOS to profile a C++ application built with CMake. The binary has been built with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`.

I need to pass a command line argument to the process, so the easiest thing seemed to be to launch the process under instrumentation from the command line, like so:

```
instruments -t "Time Profiler" bin/warpxm -I input.inp
```

This launches fine and runs to completion, but when I open the trace, no symbols from my binary are present, and the time profiler reports time spent in raw memory addresses:

[image: no symbols available]

However, when I run the process from the command line, note the PID, and then quickly create a recording from the Instruments GUI, like so:

[image: manual attachment via GUI]

then symbols are present:

[image: now with symbols]

**The only way I can get debug symbols to appear in my profile are if I set the target from the Instruments GUI**. To summarize:

These methods work:

- Run the process from the command line and find it in the list of running processes in the Instruments GUI (pictured above).
- Find the built binary in the "Choose Target" menu and record its execution without any command line args. This crashes immediately for lack of input, but it does at least give me the function name and signature of the app entry point.

These methods do not work:

- Launch the process via `instruments` on the command line: `instruments -t "..." bin/warpxm -I input.inp`
- Run the process and then immediately attach to it via `instruments`, like `instruments -t "..." -p <PID>`
- Launch the process via `xcrun xctrace record` on the command line: `xcrun xctrace record --template "..." --launch -- bin/warpxm -I input.inp`
- Run the process and then immediately attach to it via `xcrun xctrace record`, like `xcrun xctrace record --template "..." --attach <PID>`

My question is this: how can I get a profile launched from the CLI, using  either `instruments` or `xcrun xctrace record`, to include deubg symbols?